Cannot disable Google Play services
I can not disable my Google Play services because my old Samsung J7 (SM-J700H) phone does not let me disable the administrator privileges of Google Play services.
I am trying to do this because my phone has been giving me a repeated error since yesterday that

Unfotunately, Google Play services have stopped working.

I thought that if I uninstalled this, it might do the job. But whenever I try to disable/uninstall it, it says it has administrator privileges. The privileges it has is the "Find my Device" option turned on. When I try to turn that off, Settings stop working too, so I am pretty much boxed here.
Here are the fixes I have tried.

I deleted the cache of the Google Play Store.
I deleted all the cache partitions of the phone.

These fixes did not do the job and I am here for any kind of help.

Google Play Services are a core component of Google Android phones. Without it all Google apps and a lot of third party apps won't run. Instead of disabling it you should better clear it's app data (not only cache) and try to update it by installing a newer version manually.

Tried it but when try to clear data that message pops up again and goes back to settings

You need to clear cache and clear data for all Google Play and Google Play Services apps that you find in the Settings>Apps.
Then restart your phone.

When i try to clear data the message pops up again and it goes back to settings
